# Remove trailing '+' sign in this output resulting from double for loops in C

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, printf

In the code attached, how do I modify it to remove Remove the trailing '+' signs.

```
int i,j,sum;
sum=1;

for(i=2; i<=10; i++) {
    for(j=1; j<(i+1); j++) {
        sum = sum + 1;
        printf("%d + ",j);
    }
    printf(" = %d", sum);
    printf("\n");
}

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

}

Here is the output:

```
1 + 2 +  = 3
1 + 2 + 3 +  = 6
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 +  = 10
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 +  = 15
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 +  = 21
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 +  = 28
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 +  = 36
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 +  = 45
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 +  = 55
```

Comment: As a special case, print the first addend without any `+`.  Print all other addends with a leading `+` instead of a trailing one.

Comment: Instead of removing it, you could just not add it. You can tell easily which value of `j` is the last one.

Comment: Or as a special case you could not print the trailing `+` if `j == i`, or IOW  on the last run of the inner for loop.

Comment: It's amusing to see that you obtained the good result by doing something completly strange. `sum` seem to be the sum of all the previous number, but in your code, the only thing you do is incrementing it ... I advise that you reset `sum` between the 2 for loop statement and instead of incrementing sum, add the current number that is printed. You will have the same result visualy, but it will make much more sense in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I will try your suggestion as well. Honestly I came up with the solution via trial and error and now I will try to refine my answer. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you can do it the following way

```
for(j=1; j<(i+1); j++) {
    sum = sum + 1;
    if ( j != 1 ) printf( " + " );
    printf("%d",j);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vlad That solved it. So I guess the idea is not to have the '+' inside the printf() which has the successive sums but rather to treat the '+' separately as part of an if. I thought about this problem for a bit and didn't think of that. It makes sense now.

Comment: @MohamedNabassoua You are right.

Answer (score 0):

You can't 'remove' output; you have to avoid generating it.

One way is to use:

```c
for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i++)
{
    int sum = 0;
    const char *pad = "";
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {
        sum += j;
        printf("%s%d", pad, j);
        pad = " + ";
    }
    printf(" = %d\n", sum);
}
```

Note that this recalculates `sum` more directly, setting it to zero before the inner loop.  It also minimizes the scope of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can set and print the initial value in the outer loop. For my opinion also make it more readable.
Furthermore you can use j  instead of  sum+1 for the addend

```
for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {
    int sum = 1;
    printf("%d", sum);
    for (int j = 2; j<(i + 1); j++) {
        sum += j;
        printf(" + %d", j);
    }
    printf(" = %d", sum);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) will help people understand the reasons for your code suggestion.